# Panda3d Showbase class error

Tags: python, 3d, panda3d

I'm just beggining panda3d on python until a came across a problem with the showbase.py module in the panda3d folder( Which is in site-packages. `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`) I'm running on a raspberry pi 3B. The location of Showbase.py is `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/panda3d/direct/src/showbase)`

**Code :**

```
from panda3d.direct.src.showbase import *

class Window(ShowBase):

    def __init__(self):

        Showbase.__init__(self)

game = Window()
game.run()
```

I'm not going to show Showbase.py because it's 3025 lines long :|

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Pandas3D/window.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Window(ShowBase):
NameError: name 'ShowBase' is not defined
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to import the ShowBase class is to import it from the ShowBase module inside the `direct.showbase` package:

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
```

Note that the module is named `ShowBase` and the class inside it is also named `ShowBase`, hence the duplication.  A common error is to try to import the module instead of the class.

It seems from your code that you have copied the `direct` source tree into the `panda3d` package inside site-packages.  This is not how Panda is meant to be used.  The `direct` tree should be a separate package, and should not have an intervening `src` directory.

Also, you have a capitalisation error in `Showbase.__init__` which should be `ShowBase.__init__`.

Comment: I still get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Pandas3D/ShowbaseTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from direct.showbase.Showbase import ShowBase
ImportError: No module named 'direct

Comment: Could you elaborate how you installed Panda3D onto your machine, step by step?

Comment: I am on raspberry pi and I installed it using pip3 install panda3d. But when I try it again it gives me an error:  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement panda3d (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for panda3d

Comment: It's not possible to install Panda3D via `pip` on the raspberry pi.

Comment: Kk, how do I do it then?

Comment: You'll need to compile it from source.  We don't provide binary builds for the raspberry pi at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

so you need to use a super function and inherit from the `showBase` class

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase

class Window(ShowBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

app = Window()
app.run()
```

try that